# Existe algum erro em "Se encontrar alguma inconformidade , ligar para o número xxxxxxx"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, verbos, tempo-verbal

Num carro de condução encontrei o seguinte anúncio: "Se encontrar alguma inconformidade , ligar para o número xxxxxxx". Existe algum erro?

O verbo como está no infinito não representa uma inconformidade?
Não deveria ser "Se encontrar alguma inconformidade , por favor, ligue para o número xxxxxxx"

Comment: Como diz aqui, o infinitivo pode ser usado imperativamente: https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbos-no-infinitivo/.

Comment: O que é um carro de condução??

Comment: Escola de condução

Comment: Além do espaço antes da vírgula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, não há erro.

Como Schilive comentou, o infinitivo [pode ser usado](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbos-no-infinitivo/) com sentido imperativo. A preferência pelo imperativo ou pelo infinitivo [é questão de estilo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/os-verbos-no-imperativo-ou-no-infinitivo-nos-manuais-de-instrucoes/24266), com o infinitivo me parecendo ter um caráter mais pragmático, lacônico — sendo frequentemente usado em instruções escritas, como manuais e receitas.